# Looking For Excel Formula Inverse (Valleys) Of Post "Find Local Maxima With Multicell Peak"

Tags: microsoft-excel

The accepted answer to this post:

[Find Local Maxima With Multicell Peak](https://superuser.com/questions/759813/excel-find-local-maxima-with-multicell-peak)

Provides some formulas to label local maxima and some VBA to apply those labels to a series on a chart.

I'm looking to have excel identify troughs or valleys as well.  Reversing the > & < signs and changing max to min does not work.

Comment: What original post?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did a very poor job articulating my problem.  For that I apologize.  I prepared  a spreadsheet with examples that explains everything but can't figure out how to attach it..

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot below, this formula is in cell E3:

```
=IF(AND(C3<0,C4>0),"min","")
```

In the language of the original post, it detects the transition from negative to positive slope.

Alternatively, you can combine max and min into a single formula:

```
=IF(AND(C3<0,C4>0),"min",IF(AND(C3>0,C4<0),"max",""))
```

[image]